# How to get height of binary tree and root to leaf path in C

Tags: c

I have a binary tree and I need to know the height(defined as the maximum level of the tree) and I also need to find the shortest path from the root to any leaf. How do I do that in C?

Comment: Sounds like homework. Also this question is far to vague for anyone to answer

Comment: 1) Traverse the tree while counting `int depth(node*n) {return n?1+max(depth(n->left),depth(n->right)):0;}`. 2) breadth first search

Answer (score 2):

Any elementary programming course will provide an answer. See http://cslibrary.stanford.edu/110/BinaryTrees.html for example.